# Вывести 5 новостей, в которых за последние 24 часа оставили больше всего комментариев

Tags: mysql

Есть 2 таблицы:

news с колонками: id_news, title_news, content_news, date_news, id_category, is_published.

comments с колонками: id_comment, id_user, id_news, comment, id_parent, date_time, is_active.

Есть некие наброски, но они весьма печальны...

```
SELECT c.*, n.title_news FROM (
  SELECT MAX(date_time) tense, id_news FROM comments
  GROUP BY id_news LIMIT 5
  ) c
  LEFT JOIN news n ON n.id_news = c.id_news;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT n.*, c.cnt
FROM news n, (SELECT COUNT(*) cnt, id_news 
              FROM comments
              WHERE date_time > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
              GROUP BY id_news 
              ORDER BY 1 DESC
              LIMIT 5
             ) c
WHERE n.id_news = c.id_news;
```

PS. Да, наброски были печальные... получать максимальное ВРЕМЯ, когда нужно отбирать по КОЛИЧЕСТВУ - это сильно.